# Change image x and y co-ordinate on mouse hover

Tags: java, jquery, css, ajax

I have one image what I want to is: change its x & y position on mouse move.

for example:

```html
 <div class="mover" id="1">
  <IMG SRC="images/buttons1.png" WIDTH=129 HEIGHT=30 ALT="" border="0"/>
 </div>

 <div class="mover" id="2">
  <IMG SRC="images/buttons2.png" WIDTH=129 HEIGHT=30 ALT="" border="0"/>
 </div>
```

What I want to do is like normal flash menus
when my mouse come on " buttons1.png " a blue dot image show in the beginning of button and
when mouse leave the " buttons1.png " this blue dot disappear.

I want to repeat same for my both images.

Comment: -poke- Have you solved this problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

- [JQuery.position](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/position)
- [JQuery.css](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#namevalue)
- [JQuery.mouseenter](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseenter#fn) and [JQuery.mouseleave](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseleave#fn)

Example:

```js
$(".button").mouseenter(function()
{
    var position = $(this).position();

    $("#dot").css("left", position.left+10)
             .css("top", position.top+5)
             .show();
}).mouseleave(function()
{
    $("#dot").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mover" id="2">
  <img class="button" src="images/buttons1.png" width="129" height="30"/>
  <img class="button" src="images/buttons2.png" width="129" height="30"/>
</div>
<img id="dot" style="display: none; position: absolute;" src="images/blue_dot.png"/>
```